# I tried register form in android using Php,MySQL and response using JSON parsing,but details are not inserted in the table

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

When I click the register button,nothing happens in backend no details are entered in the table.It seems there is no error in the code.I think the URL which I am using is the problem.Please help me in this.

RegisterRequest.java

```
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL="http://192.168.1.40/Register.php";
    private Map<String,String> params;
    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, int age, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age + "");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Register Activity code:

```
package com.login.sowmy.loginregister;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        final EditText etAge=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final EditText etName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUserName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
        final EditText etPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bRegister=(Button) findViewById(R.id.BRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String name=etName.getText().toString();
                final String username=etUserName.getText().toString();
                final String password=etPassword.getText().toString();
                final int age=Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());
                Response.Listener<String> responseLister= new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success=jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
                            if(success){
                                Intent i=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry",null).create().show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest=new RegisterRequest(name,username,age,password,responseLister);
                RequestQueue queue=  Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have added internet permission in manifest file and included compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0' in build gradle.My android version is 2.2.3

Below is the php code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employee11");
$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $age, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: are you getting any response from the server?

Comment: no.I am not getting response.I am doubtful that whether it hits the server or not

Comment: why don't you check logcat window on the IDE if some issues are logged

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the api using postman. If its ok then check from volley.And your api is returning json array ['success':'true']. So see the following code.

```
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest FormPostRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    // Parsing json
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            Toast.makeText(this, obj.getString("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(FormPostRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1** make  db_connect.php

```
 // change the credential which is required for HOST,USER,PASS,DB
<?php
 define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USER','root');
 define('PASS','Root@123');
 define('DB','db name');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
 ?>
```

**Step 2**  make one more file get.php

**2.1** include db_connect.php file into this

**2.2** table name and column name should be same like database

```
  <?php

include 'db_connect.php';
$datetime = date('d/m/Y');
$request=$_REQUEST['getdata'];

 // customer Registration form
if($request=="registerCustomer")
        {

        $user_Name =$_REQUEST['name'];

        $user_age =$_REQUEST['age'];

        $user_userName =$_REQUEST['username'];

        $user_password =$_REQUEST['password'];

    // sql query with database column name and table name should be same as in database

        $insert_Values=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `user`(`name`, `username`, `age`, `password`)
                                             VALUES ('$user_Name','$user_userName','$user_age','$user_password')");  

                if($insert_Values)
                {
                    $flag["code"]="data inserted";
                }
                else
                {
                    $flag["code"]="data not inserted";
                }


            print(json_encode($flag));    
        }
else
{

    $flag['Error']='2';
    print(json_encode($flag));      

}       
?>
```

**Step 3**  In Android you are using Volley. so please refer below code .

```
3.1 create one `VolleyAppController` which `extends application` check below code 


public class VolleyAppController extends Application {

    // this methode is for multidex install For Map and google Api
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    public static final String TAG = VolleyAppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static VolleyAppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized VolleyAppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }


}
```

**3.2**  in android `menifest` you need to do changes.
            1)Add above class to android menifest
            2)   `android:name=".VolleyAppController"`

```
 <application
        android:name=".Volley.VolleyAppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**3.3**  1)you just need to pass the parameter and check the responce.

```
        2)i have created one methode use that methode and call that methode from where you want to insert data

        3) take care of params.put("name","Value");  
        4) In get.php  $_REQUEST['name'];  
        5) params.put("name") and $_REQUEST['name'] should be same



 public void insertCustomerData() {

        Log.e(TAG, CustomerURL);
        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registration is in Process Please wait...");
        pDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                CustomerURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        pDialog.hide();

                        Log.e("responce", response);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {


                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("getdata", "registerCustomer");

                params.put("name", "Yogesh");
                params.put("age", "25");
                params.put("username", "YogeshBorhade");
                params.put("password", "password");
```

// i have putted static data insted of that you can put string over there

```
                return params;
            }


        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        VolleyAppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

    }
```

**If you have any doubt please let me know..**

**In your code your query is wrong you can refer this code and do the changes which you want.**